# How to translate between a C Structure and a Cpp Structure with virtual inheritence?

Tags: c++, c, inheritance

I write a Function

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) PEParserHandle* __cdecl openFile(PEParserHandle* ppEParserHandle) noexcept {
   
   openFile<>(/*pointer to Cpp class*/)
   return &ppEParserHandle;
};
```

that takes a pointer to a C Structure `PEParserHandle*` as argument/param,
and returns pointer `return &ppEParserHandle`.
This Function calls the "Real" Function that looks the following

```
template<class PEParserBaseImpl>
inline PEParserBaseImpl& openFile(PEParserBaseImpl* pPEParserBaseImpl) noexcept {
   //does some irrelevant stuff
   return *pPEParserBaseImpl;
    };
```

How ever, the "Real Function" takes a class as arg/param. So I need to translate inside my "wrapper" Function.
I dont want to copy Data around much, inside the "Wrapper" Function.
And I am not really allowed, able nor want to change anything inside the "Real" Function, nor changing the cpp classes and (idealy) the C Structure.

Below you can see the C Structures

```
typedef struct PEParserFunctionExecutionLog {
    bool failed;
    union alignas(__int64) {
        //unrelevant
    } code;
} *pPEParserFunctionExecutionLog;
typedef struct PEParserSignatur {
    //unrelevant
} *pPEParserSignatur;
typedef struct PEParser
{
    unsigned int PEParserStructurType;
    union {
        PEParserFunctionExecutionLog pEParserFunctionExecutionLog;
        PEParserSignatur pEParserSignatur;
    }Dummy;
} *pPEParser;


typedef struct PEParserHandle
{
    pPEParser ppEParser;        
    //unrelevant
} *pPEParserHandle;
typedef struct PEParserHeader
{
    //unrelevant
} *pPEParserHeader;


typedef struct PEParserCombined
{
    PEParser pEParser;
    PEParserHandle pEParserHandle;
    PEParserHeader pEParserHeader;
    //One Struct for everything
} *pPEParserCombined;
```

Below you can see the Cpp Classes/Structs

```
typedef struct functionExecutionLog {
    bool failed;
    union alignas(__int64) {
        //unrelevant
    } code;
} PEParserfunctionExecutionLog;
typedef struct signatur {
    //unrelevant
} PEParsersignatur;

struct PEParserBase :
    virtual public functionExecutionLog,
    virtual public signatur 
{
    //unrelevant
};
typedef struct PEHEADER : 
    virtual public functionExecutionLog,
    virtual public signatur 
{
    //unrelevant
} PEParserHeader;
struct PEParser : 
    public PEParserBase, 
    public PEParserHeader
{
    //One Class for everything
};
```

I know that I cant just cast between `PEParserHandle*` and my Cpp class(es) that looks like diamand and uses virtual Inheritence.
I have heard about dynamic_cast<>() but it uses RTTI, and would like to avoid that RTTI overhead(even if it would not be a big deal).
I have thought of somekind of "intermediate" simple (generic) Cpp Class that names the hidden pointers, and lets say a (generic) function that translates my C struct to the cpp class, and vise versa.

Some Ideas how to implement or alternatives?

Comment: boiling all down to the base, you will not get past the need to somehow convert a PEParserHandle to a PEParserBaseImpl. Either you write a converter on your own, or (with a little bit of luck), the implementation of PEParserBaseImpl already knows about the "old" way and offers some constructor to work upon a PEParserHandle or similar.

Comment: Without knowing the details about your classes and structure it is difficult to suggest specific solutions.

Comment: Can you simplify your naming conventions please? These names are too confusing. Use `*` for pointers instead of undeclared `typedef`s. Make the snippets readable for us. Keep us away from the required naming conventions inside your project.